# Is there a pythonic way to iterate through the difference of two lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

My goal is to iterate through the difference of two lists

I attempted a bodge code to write a - b as follows

```py
for i in a:
        if i in b:
            continue
        #statements
```

I was wondering if there was a more pythonic/efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [sets](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), to look at the difference:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [2, 4, 6]

a = set(a)
b = set(b)

for i in a.difference(b):
    print(i)

# even supports the arithmetic syntax :D
for i in a - b:
    print(i)
```

Comment: much faster too

Comment: would writing set(a)-set(b) be just the same? as I have further use of a and b as lists in the code.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of sets, the items in `a` but not in `b` would be the set difference, therefore this would be

```
for i in set(a).difference(b):
    # statements
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is fine. If you object to the `continue` statement, you can iterate over a generator:

```
for i in (x for x in a if x not in b):
```

though that is arguably worse in terms of readability.